# Split string and search in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a website with long table. I created a searchbar where a user can filter the table with.
I want that the input from the searchbar get splitted on each 3 characters and the website filters each splitted group.

For example: If a user types in `Tomato` it gets split into `Tom` and `ato` and the site searches for `Tom` and `ato` in the table.

This is the code I have now

The searchbar:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search_text").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTabletr:not(.th)").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="searchbar">
  <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" onkeyup="myFunction()" />
</div>
```

Can anyone help me, thanks :)

Comment: What have you tried, what exactly do you need help _with_? The splitting the string part must surely be something you researched already, right …?

Comment: You may want to use the string.substr method [substr mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr). You may want to know how many parts you may need. After do a loop for each substring you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to split the string into an array of 3 character strings.

```js
value.match(/.{1,3}/g)
```

You can then use that array to do your search.

Note: Say that value is 8 characters long, this will give you an array like so: ["123", "456", "78"]. If you only want 3 character segments use {3} instead of {1,3}.